# Create Unique ID per Form Submitted

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, form, nintex

I'm looking to create a unique ID for each Form submitted. I'm using SharePoint Online.

The format is ["AN"-YY#####]

First form would look like: AN-1900001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can activate the Document ID service site collection feature and configure the Document ID setting for static text and format(from site collection settings page >site collection administration >document ID settings)....

More about this :
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/document-id-service-in-sharepoint-2013/

If you want to customize this more dynamic way.... you can create another calculated column based on this document id column or can create sample workflow using MS Flow or Nintex.

Comment: Thanks. This will consider a Nintex Form (submitted into a list) as a new document? How will it know to sequentially count upwards (e.g. AN-1900001 to AN-1900002)?

Comment: I'm really just looking for a column with an auto-increment by one digit every time a form is submitted.

Comment: @AndrewStreaman : Here is a detailed steps how we can do using Nintex Form: https://community.nintex.com/t5/Community-Blogs/Creating-An-Incremental-Number-That-Avoids-Concurrency-Problems/ba-p/76773          https://community.nintex.com/t5/Nintex-for-SharePoint/Sequential-numbering/td-p/10785

Comment: Thank you Habibur!